# Comparing numpy datatypes to strings

Tags: python, numpy

Many numpy functions take dtype arguments as either strings (like `"float64"`) or numpy datatypes (like `numpy.float64`) or even python datatypes (like `float`).

I need to compare two datatypes and want to support this flexible interface. Is there a function under which all of these are forms are equivalent? I.e. I want the minimal function `f` such that

`f("float64") == f(numpy.float64) == f(float)`

What does numpy use internally?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should read the [Scalars](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) page of the numpy documentation, which describes the data type hierarchy.

For comparing dtypes themselves, you can use [np.issubdtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html). Some examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.issubdtype(np.int32, int)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.int32, float)
False
>>> np.issubdtype(float, np.floating)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(float, np.inexact)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.float32, float)
True
>>> np.issubdtype(np.float32, int)
False
>>> np.issubdtype(np.float32, np.floating)
True
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of subdtype comparison. Nice.

Comment: Looks preferable to `'int' in a.dtype.name`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it would be to create a new `numpy.dtype` object each time, as it has all the necessary type normalization/standardization and equality-checking already built in. Actually, I haven't taken a look at the internals, so it's possible that it doesn't actually create a new instance of `dtype` for ones that `numpy` already has (like how using `numpy.array` doesn't always create a new array), which would be nicely efficient.

```
numpy.float64 == numpy.dtype('float64') == numpy.dtype(numpy.float64) == numpy.dtype(float)
numpy.int32 == numpy.dtype('int32') == numpy.dtype(numpy.int32) == numpy.dtype(int)
```